# Flutter duplicate if statement with multiple widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter, I see I can't use if statement with  curly braces but what if I have the below code, do I have to repeat if statement in every widget?

Block1

```
    if(product.length>0)
    Container(..)
   
   if(product.length>0)
     Divider(..),
```

block2

```
   else
    Container(...)
    Expanded(..)
```

so I can't use curly here but what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: provide full code

Comment: explain in brief what actually you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Use the `...[` block to display multiple widgets conditionally

```dart
if(product.length>0) ...[
    Container(..),
    Container(..)
] else ...[
  const SizedBox(),
  Container(..),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if else` statements with and without curly braces.

1. Using Curly braces:

```dart
if(product.length>0){
    // Some other code here
    Container(..)
}else{
    Placeholder(..)
}
```

2. Without curly braces:

```dart
if(product.length>0)
    Container(..)
// some code NOTE: THIS IS NOT A PART OF THE IF ELSE STATEMENT
// WITHOUT CURLY BRACES YOU CAN HAVE ONLY ONE STATEMENT INSIDE IF-ELSE
```

It is always recommended to use curly braces to avoid confusion.

**EDIT:**

Also a more clean approach would be ternary operators:

```dart
return Container(child: product.length>0 ? Text() : Placeholder());
```

If the condition evaluated to `true` then, 1st expression is evaluated and returned, otherwise 2nd expression is evaluated and returned.

You can read more about it here: [Conditional Expression - Dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions)

Comment: if I used curly I will get error The element type 'Set<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Comment: @IsmailMuhammad Updated the answer! Does it help?

Comment: no it is not what I need, my question is if I have block with multiple widget like containers, rows.. and I want to use if to show this block, other wise to show other block, I think it should works if I used if without curly but Im not sure if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ternary operator. Also you don't need to add if statement above all the widgets, you can add that all widget inside one Column().For example:
product.length>0 ? Container() : Column()